# Triggering multiple events based on change event of one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have multiple rows with three select elements each. There are two such rows during initialization and further rows can be added dynamically. I added change events to all these elements when each row is added such that all the other elements in a particular row change when one of the drop downs in that row is changed. There is also another select element `#foo` that is not a part of any row (it is displayed on top of the page) which on change should change the contents of all the select elements on all rows.

I tried doing this by adding `jQuery("#foo select").change(callback_function)` while adding the change events for each row. But when I do this, changing `#foo` updates only the last inserted row and not the other rows. How do I make it work in such a way that changing `#foo` updates all rows?

Any solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer if you provided some source code, but from what I understand (When the `select` element with an id of `foo` is changed, the other `select` elements are changed by  a certain function) this might work for you:

```
$("#foo").on('change', function() {
  $('select.other-selects').each( function (i) {
    callback_function();
  });
});
```

Where `.other-selects` is the class you designete you others `select` elements with.

Comment: I'm already doing this by adding a change event handler specific to that row `jQuery("#foo select").change(callback_function)`. When I do this, the change events for the previous rows should also be retained. Why can't a single element have multiple change events bound to it?